# MySQL queries very slow on join statements

Tags: mysql, join

So i have two tables:

```
| id     | make      | model        | color    |
| 1234   | BMW       | M2           | blue     |
| 2345   | Audi      | A3           | black    |
```

and

```
| id     | date       | price       | 
| 1234   | 2015-09-23 | 34000       | 
| 1234   | 2015-10-23 | 33500       |
```

The first table has about 500000 unique vehicles. The second table has the price from the vehicle of everyday for a few days (will be more in the future)

Now I want to execute a simple join statement:

```
SELECT        count(v.id)
FROM          nm_voertuig v
JOIN          nm_voertuig_statistieken vs
ON            v.id = vs.id
WHERE         model = 'BRZ'
```

If I remove the join its really fast, but with the join it costs about 20 seconds to load. 
I have tried to add some indexes. But it doesn't seem to help.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Indexes in nm_voertuig:
https://gyazo.com/cd1628862574ee3c7beb0520484819cc

**EDIT 2**
This is the result from EXPLAIN:
https://gyazo.com/18c1ad77718e8cdf9d19a3846cc4472c

Comment: indexes on what? the rule of thumb is to put indexes on all fields involved in "decision" contexts: `join`, `where`, `order by`, etc... a select count() can be essentially instantaneous on some table types, because the row count is stored in the table's metadata, and the db doesn't have to count actual records.

Comment: Which fields do your indexes contain?

Comment: I don't really know how indexes work. Will edit my post with the indexes

Comment: You probably need an index on id for the other table, nm_voertuig_statistieken, But don't guess: inspecting execution plans would show what index lookups and full table scans are taking place.

Comment: I'm using Navicat and php mysqli to use the database. How can I get theses execution plans?

Comment: execute in Navicat: EXPLAIN SELECT        count(v.id)
FROM          nm_voertuig v
JOIN          nm_voertuig_statistieken vs
ON            v.id = vs.id
WHERE         model = 'BRZ'; and post the result

Comment: @BerndBuffen Edited my main post with the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Wouter den Ouden :

i have seen that your query use the index.

try this: first get fast the count and only join for one row and not for all.

```
SELECT cnt.*, vs.* FROM (
    SELECT        count(v.id), id
    FROM          nm_voertuig v
    WHERE         model = 'BRZ'
  ) AS cnt  
JOIN          nm_voertuig_statistieken vs
ON            cnt.id = vs.id;
```

please let me know if it works for you